# How to set texture interpolation for Empty Images?

Tags: texturing, interpolation, empty

You can change the texture interpolation for images used as textures for objects in the Image node under the Shader Editor.
[image: Demonstration for texture interpolation]
[image: Demonstration for texture interpolation]
Here you can change it to various interpolation method, in this example I've changed it to closest from linear.

But how do I do the same for Empty Images? I don't seem to find any settings related to it.
[image: No settings for texture interpolation for empty images]

Comment: Sorry, I don't think you can change interpolation for empty images. May I ask why you are using an empty image in the first place? Empty's contain essentially no data and do not appear in renders. Would using _Image(s) as plane(s)_ work better? You could still disable it for renders if need be, and at least you would get the image options back.

Comment: @Christopher I need to model something with very high precision, snapping to increments or the grid won't work as some pixels are not on the grid. The linear interpolation makes it even harder to eyeball the position. Using 'Images as planes' would solve the interpolation problem, but since it'd be opaque it won't be the right choice, going to x-ray mode will also not work. I dunno I'm running out of options, Blender should add this feature for empty images too...

Comment: "something with very high precision" doesn't sound very serious when talking about pixel interpolation. Sounds like you need better reference in any case.

Comment: I can't get higher resolution blueprints, it was a big image with multiple blueprints for different objects. I just cropped out the one I needed. The original file was a .dwg file then i had to convert it to .png(which may have reduced the quality), and then i cropped it out... but still, blender should add this feature for empty images too

Comment: If you have DWG file, convert the drawings to DXF format and import them to Blender. It is a big mistake to convert vector drawings to bitmaps and then use that for reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a DWG file, you should definitely forget about any bitmap formats and import it as geometry to Blender. Blender supports SVG and DXF formats. Most CAD software can export technical drawings in DXF format. If you choose the correct unit size for exporting to Blender which is 1m, they will even import the correct size.

Then you can have the drawings as geometry:

[image]

You can keep the actual exact measurements and snap stuff to the drawings without worrying about numbers, or even use parts of the drawings as starting geometry for modelling stuff. It would be a nightmare to work on complex projects requiring technical drawings if they were in bitmap formats.

Comment: Yes, I do have a DWG file, but it's just a plain drawing of the model on different axes. I viewed it on an online DWG file viewer as I currently don't have any CAD software. I then screen-shotted and cropped it with pixel precision, so that when Blender interpolates the texture it'd be subtle. Not a big fan of this method, but it works ok...